# Automapper with Anonymous list in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, automapper, anonymous-types

I'm having a problem getting Automapper to work correctly with Lists of anonymous types VB.Net. I've found a few examples on-line in C# but cannot get them to compile let alone work once converted to VB.Net. Code below is a simplified version of what I am trying to do. The errors I am getting with the code below are "Type argument cannot be inferred from usage" on the select and "Incorrect number of arguments" in DynamicMap but I have tried loads of variations each fixes one problem and creates at least one more.

Any help would be much appreciated as I have been looking at this for over a day.

```
Public Function OrgList() As List(Of OrganisationListSelectVm)
    Dim orgs = (From o In EntityModel.Organisations
    Join r In EntityModel.Regions On o.RegionID Equals r.RegionID
    Order By o.OrganisationName
    Select
        o.OrganisationID,
        o.OrganisationName,
        o.OrganisationCode,
        o.RegionID,
        r.RegionName).ToList()

    '** mapping one item works fine
    Dim oneItem = Mapper.DynamicMap(Of OrganisationListSelectVm)(orgs(0))

    '** C# mapper from various web sites
    'var result = orgs.Select(Mapper.DynamicMap<OrganisationListSelectVm>).ToList();

    '** VB converted type which fails
    Dim result As List(Of OrganisationListSelectVm) = orgs.[Select](Mapper.DynamicMap(Of OrganisationListSelectVm)).ToList()


    Return result
End Function
```